# Foundation SASS/SCSS Variables

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I am trying to move over from Bootstrap to Zurb Foundation.

Bootstrap uses *-color for text colour and *-bg for background colours.

I'm a little confused with Foundation's naming scheme:

What is the difference between `$topbar-link-bg-hover`and `$topbar-link-bg-color-hover`?

Both their names suggest that they change the background colour of a link in the top bar, both are given a colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation structure has lots of details, if you search these variables in Foundation you can find them in `_top-bar.scss` file. Look at it, how used these variables:

```
// Apply the hover link color when it has that class
&:hover:not(.has-form) > a {
    background-color: $topbar-link-bg-color-hover;

    @if ($topbar-link-bg-hover) {
        background: $topbar-link-bg-hover;
    }
}
```

`$topbar-link-bg-color-hover` value can equal with color because use for `background-color` and `$topbar-link-bg-hover` value can equal with image or anything else(background css values).